# Strange ORDER BY order in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by, postgresql-9.1

```
SELECT vm.value FROM vm ORDER BY vm.value ASC;
```

results in:

```
.
0
0%
0.0
0.964
%.0f
%.0f mph
-1.0°
11/1
11-14-1981
112 mph
11:48:43
%1$.1f mph %2$@
1/2
12.5˚
1/4
195 lb
%.1f°
2 days ago
%.2f
2º out-in
3/4
3.5
3.6
3D
3 days ago
4º closed
5'10''
5”10”
Account
```

I can remember that ASCII/Unicode digits should follow each other tightly not alternated with percents and other characters.

Comment: Looks like percents, dots and other special characters are just ignored during comparison.

Comment: What is the column type of `vm.value`?

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson: character varying(1000)

Comment: As ordering is governed by your locale, What is your locale set to?  Try switching to the C locale and see if that changes it.

Comment: I thought that ORDER BY should be universal, locale-independent as is the Unicode itself. BTW: how to change/view locale?

Comment: Are you sure isn't there any spaces or non-printable characters on this? The interchange of "%" seems odd to me (e.g. all string starting with "%" should be together).

Comment: @MatheusOl http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/ef790/4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I can remember that ASCII/Unicode digits should follow each other
>   tightly not alternated with percents and other characters.

This applies to some locales but not others. Obviously it doesn't apply to the one you're using. Issue `show lc_collate` in SQL to see what locale is in use.

With recent versions of PG, including 9.1, you may use a per-query specific locale to sort, like this:

```
SELECT vm.value FROM vm ORDER BY vm.value COLLATE "C";
```

For the specific data shown in the question, this would sort as you expect.

Comment: `en_US.UTF-8` sorts in the manner the question describes. One would think that collation wouldn't disregard non alphanumerics.

Comment: Yes, I am using en_US.UTF-8

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Where is `en_US.UTF-8` collation order documented?